# How to catch Whitespace on TextBox prefore it occurs

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm creating a custom control called `SearchBox`, which has a `ControlTemplate` with a textbox called `searchTextBox`.

I have a handlee for `searchTextBox.TextChanged` event that does some processing, but I want to have a different method that handles whitespace.

I can't use `PreviewTextInput` event as it is not fired on whitespace. I also tried handling `PreviewKeyDown` but it seems to have unpredictable behavior where sometimes it catches the whitespace and sometimes it doesn't.

How can I catch a whitespace before it occurs on a `TextBox`?

Comment: you should also handle Copy&Paste

Comment: Why do you want a different method to handle whitespace? What do you want to do with the whitespace?

Comment: @Björn the `SearchBox` has a suggestions box displayed. on whitespace it should apply the suggestion and do some other logic. It should also NOT show the space on the `TextBox` itself ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers but non of the above actually worked for me.
I ended up checking for the tailing character in the `TextChanged` event

```
if (Text.EndsWith(" "))
    HandleWhitespace();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to listen to the event PreviewKeyDown and do your processing there?

**Edit 1**: By using PreviewKeyDown you won't be able to process pasted text I guess.

**Edit 2**:
In a project I have created a derived textbox which overrides the OnPreviewKeyDown:

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Space)
    {
        //Prevent spaces (space does not "raise" OnPreviewTextInput)
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

In this case I did not want the textbox to do anything with space. Maybe you could do something similar? Maybe raise a custom event if there is a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try `PreviewKeyDown`as well as `TextChanged`.

Not all keys are captured in `TextChanged`. Backspace is a prime offender.

If you modify the text within either event handler, be sure to save and restore the current selection to the best of your ability. If you do not, the carat will always toggle to the start of the textbox and this is very annoying for users.

**Why both?**

Non-key operations like pasting and cutting text will not trigger `PreviewKeyDown`.

Comment: I did try `PreviewKeyDown` (I had a typo in my question) and there's no such an event called `PreviewTextChanged`

Comment: @Omribitan Consider it a brain fart. There is no such event :D I shall remove the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `KeyDown` event and do something like:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        // handle whitespace
    }
}
```

If you don't want to whitespace to appear on the textbox you can set `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`

Answer (score 0):

As etaiso answered, you can assigned the KeyDown or PreviewKeyDown event. etaiso's answer is based on windows form not wpf. You can specifiy the e.Handle = ture instead of SuppressKeyPress

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        e.Hanlded = true; // SuppressKeyPress is for windows form
    }
}
```